# How to hide default choose file button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I hide the default choose file button ?

Here is my html:

```
<div class="col-md-4">                           
    <span class="btn btn-info "><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"> </i> Browse
        <input type="file" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden" id="inPutArtistImage" name="ArtistImage" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" />
    </span>
</div>
```

The button is styled nicely with bootsrap button info colors and the plus icon.

I simply cannot get rid of the grey "Choose file" button.
Any help is appreciated.

I have tried every solution on StackOverflow

Answer (score 32):

UPDATE 2021

You can use

```
::-webkit-file-upload-button {
   display: none;
}
```

I found another solution that works even in non-WebKit browsers

```
::file-selector-button {
  display: none;
}
```

It hides the "choose file" button but the file name is still visible.
If you also want to hide the file name, just target the whole `input` with `display:none`

Comment: Just what I was looking for.. thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm looking for exact same effect. Am I wondering though, what happens with non-Webkit browsers?

Comment: @Vladyn thanks for asking, I've just edited my answer and added a cross-browser solution.

Comment: Note, this solution hides the entire input on Safari. This gist should work for all modern browsers: https://gist.github.com/perrygovier/3193ba18b63079ff2615d6b263c077f5

Comment: Thank you very much - was looking for that sollution

Comment: It's very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Simple. Give the `input` enough `padding-top` so that it hides. **Do not forget to do the `box-sizing` thing!!**

```css
input#file {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 120px 0 0 0;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698394-icon-130-cloud-upload-512.png') center center no-repeat #e4e4e4;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-size: 60px 60px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="file" type="file" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you might be looking for

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b5r1js06/2/)

What i did here is hide the original input using `display: none` style on it and using jQuery `click()` on another div to simulate the click on the input.

**NOTE:** I have used `split('\\')` to escape `\` as it is used in the fakepath returned from the file chooser.

Comment: This doesnt display the name of the chosen file

Answer (score 1):

Looking for several answers through Stackoverflow and other tutorials, I ended up doing this code:

```js
$('#selectedFile').change(function () {
    var a = $('#selectedFile').val().toString().split('\\');
    $('#fakeInput').val(a[a.length -1]);
});
```

```css
input#fakeInput {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display:block;
  padding: 11px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border:initial;
  height: 3em;
}
#buttonImage {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #02a39c;
  padding:10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
  height:1.25em;
}
#fakeDiv {
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
#selectedFile {
  opacity:0;
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fakeDiv">
  <input type="file" id="selectedFile" />
  <input type="text" id="fakeInput" />
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('selectedFile').click();" id="buttonImage" >Browse</span>
</div>
```

Basically, you have to do it in a tricky way.

1. Create an **input type="file"**, make it invisible (with opacity or visibility property, if you set display=none, it won't work).
2. Put a regular input and format it as you wish
3. Put a fake button (in my case a span)
4. Make the button click to launch the **input type="file"** click
5. Just fill the regular input with what you uploaded with the not visible input file

**NOTE:** If code snippet is not working (my first time posting a Code snippet) try [this JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sonhja/bvjcn09h/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Found this while searching for a nice simple css solution. Just use the following code in a linked css file:

```
input[type=file]::file-selector-button {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

credit to Nikita Hlopov, https://nikitahl.com/custom-styled-input-type-file

Answer (score -1):

In your css:

```
 input[type="file"] {
    display: none !important;
```

The !important isn't required.