# How to have a single button for upload file

Tags: jquery, html

Im trying to have a single upload file button without the choose file or submit buttons. I posted the image of my upload file button and the HTML and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction. Thanks

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm remove">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload File
</a>
```

[image]

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ I used this and it did the job for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide default choose file button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895125/how-to-hide-default-choose-file-button)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

why don't you hide your `<input type="file" id="file">` and show only your image button, when someone click your button use this code:

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="file" style="display:none;" />
<button id="button" name="button" value="Upload" onclick="thisFileUpload();">Upload</button>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script>
        function thisFileUpload() {
            document.getElementById("file").click();
        };
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use like this

```
<form id="form">
<input type="file" id=file"/> 
</form>
```

Jquery for this

```
$("#file").onchange(function () {
$("#form").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div>
    <input type="file" />
    <a href="#0" class="btn btn-info btn-sm remove">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload File
    </a>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is the CSS. It's basically positioning the input field on top of your button with opacity: 0. You can't see it but it works and it looks like your button is doing the job when it's not.

```
form div {
  position: relative;
  width: 102px;
  height: 38px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 8px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y6xk0oca/1/) to see it in action