# Get file name when css is applied to input[type=file]

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I'm trying to get the file through `input`.
I hide the input through CSS and gave the label a style. There is a problem here.

If input is hidden, the default input button cannot support the supported get file name.
I guess Vanila JS can solve this, but I don't know what to do.
I tried to get the value value of the file and put it in the box specified as inner HTML, but it didn't work.

```css
.submit{
   width:140px;
   height:40px;
   background-color:red;
   color:#fff;
   text-align:center;
   padding:10px;
   line-height:40px;
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="test" style="display:none;">
<label for="test">
    <span class="submit">submit</span>
    <span id="test2">filename</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)

Comment: Get the value value. I tried to put it through innerHTML but it didn't work.

Comment: This  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42132216/12415287) will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857618/javascript-how-to-extract-filename-from-a-file-input-control), you can get the file name, and use `innerHTML` to show it to user.

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("change", function() {
  var fullPath = document.getElementById('test').value;
  if (fullPath) {
    var startIndex = (fullPath.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? fullPath.lastIndexOf('\\') : fullPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
    var filename = fullPath.substring(startIndex);
    if (filename.indexOf('\\') === 0 || filename.indexOf('/') === 0) {
      filename = filename.substring(1);
    }
    document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = filename;;
  }
});
```

```css
.submit {
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="test" style="display:none;">
<label for="test">
    <span class="submit">submit</span>
    <span id="test2">filename</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML

```
<input type="file" id="test" style="display:none;">
<label for="test">
    <span class="submit">submit</span>
    <span id="test2">filename</span>
</label>
```

Your CSS

```
.submit{
   width:140px;
   height:40px;
   background-color:red;
   color:#fff;
   text-align:center;
   padding:10px;
   line-height:40px;
   cursor:pointer;
 }
```

And Javascript

```
let file = document.querySelector('#test');
let test2 = document.querySelector('#test2');

file.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  test2.innerHTML = e.target.files[0].name;
});
```

Demo here
https://jsfiddle.net/jozsefk/4gwzrj38/